# Conversion of decimal to Octal and Hexa (Output at the same time) - Assembly

Tags: assembly, hex, dos, x86-16, octal

I have an assembly program that should accept a decimal and convert it to octal and hexa. Currently, it can convert both but it prompts the user to input the desired value to convert twice.. I should only prompt the user once then print two outputs. I wanted to hold the inputted value in a variable and pass it to both functions that convert.

Here is my previous code:

```
.model small
.stack
.data
    CR equ 13
    lf equ 10
    Introduction db cr,lf,09H,">TEST<$"
    Students db cr,lf,09H,"    >TEST<$"
    Lab db cr,lf,09H,09H,09H,">TEST<$"
    Section db cr,lf,09h,09h,09h,09h,">TEST<$"
    Oct db cr,lf,0Ah,09H,">Octal Decimal<$"
    Hexa db cr,lf,0Ah,09H,">Hexadecimal<$"
    message1 db cr,lf,09H,"Enter a decimal number in a range of 0-65535: $"
    message3 db cr,lf,0Ah,09H,09H, "Equivalent octal number is:$"
    message4 db cr,lf,0Ah,09H,09H, "Equivalent hexadecimal number is:$"
    Again db cr,lf,0Ah,09h,"Do you want to try again?(y/n)$"
    Bye db cr,lf,0Ah,09H,09H,09H," >Thank you and Goodbye!<$"

oBuffer             dw 6
                dw 0
                    dw 6 dup(0)

oMultiplier         dw 0ah

hBuffer             dw 6
                    dw 0
                    dw 6 dup(0)

hMultiplier         dw 0ah
.code
org 100h

start:
    mov cx,0000h
    mov dx,184fh
    mov bh,21h
    mov ah,6
    int 10h

    mov dh,0
    mov dl,0
    mov bh,0
    mov ah,2
    int 10h

    mov ax,@data
    mov ds, ax

    lea dx,Introduction
    mov ah,9
    int 21h

    lea dx,Students
    mov ah,9
    int 21h

    lea dx,Lab
    mov ah,9
    int 21h

    lea dx,Section
    mov ah,9
    int 21h
    jmp Octal   
try:        
lea dx,Again
mov ah,9
int 21h

xor ah,ah
int 16h
mov bl,al

mov dl,al
mov ah,02h
int 21h

cmp bl,'Y'
je start
cmp bl,'y'
je start
cmp bl,'N'
je stop
cmp bl,'n'
je stop
stop :
lea dx,Bye
mov ah,9
int 21h

mov ax,4C00h 
int 21h 
Octal:

lea dx,Oct
mov ah,9
int 21h

mov dx,offset message1
mov ah,09h
int 21h

mov ah, 0ah
lea dx, oBuffer
int 21h

mov si, offset oBuffer + 2
mov cl, byte ptr [si-1]
mov ch, 00h
OctSubtract :
mov al, byte ptr [si]
cmp al, 30h
jnb OctCont1
jmp stop
OctCont1 :
cmp al, 3ah
jb OctCont2
jmp stop

OctCont2 :
sub al, 30h
mov byte ptr [si], al
inc si
loop OctSubtract
mov si, offset oBuffer + 2
mov cl, byte ptr [si-1]
mov ch, 00h
mov ax, 0000h
OctCalc :
mul oMultiplier
mov bl, byte ptr [si]
mov bh, 00h
add ax, bx
inc si
loop OctCalc
mov si, offset oBuffer + 2
mov bx, ax
mov dx, 0000h
mov ax, 8000h
OctOctConvert :
mov cx, 0000h
OctConv :
cmp bx, ax
jb OctCont3
sub bx, ax
inc cx
jmp OctConv
OctCont3 :
add cl, 30h
mov byte ptr [si], cl
inc si
mov cx, 0008h
div cx
cmp ax, 0000h
jnz OctOctConvert
mov byte ptr [si], '$'

lea dx,message3
mov ah,9
int 21h
mov dx, offset oBuffer + 2
int 21h

Hex:
    lea dx,Hexa
    mov ah,9
    int 21h
    lea dx,message1
    mov ah,9
    int 21h

    mov ah, 0ah
    lea dx, hBuffer
    int 21h

    mov si, offset hBuffer + 2
    mov cl, byte ptr [si-1]
    mov ch, 00h
hexsubtract :
    mov al, byte ptr [si]
    cmp al, 30h
    jnb hexcont1

    jmp stop
hexcont1 :
    cmp al, 3ah
    jb hexcont2

    jmp stop
hexcont2 :
    sub al, 30h
    mov byte ptr [si], al

    inc si
    loop hexsubtract

    mov si, offset hBuffer + 2
    mov cl, byte ptr [si-1]
    mov ch, 00h
    mov ax, 0000h
hexcalc :
    mul hMultiplier
    mov bl, byte ptr [si]
    mov bh, 00h
    add ax, bx
    inc si
    loop hexcalc

    mov si, offset hBuffer + 2
    mov bx, ax
    mov dx, 0000h
    mov ax, 1000h
hexconvert :
    mov cx, 0000h
conv :
    cmp bx, ax
    jb hexcont3
    sub bx, ax
    inc cx
    jmp conv
hexcont3 :
    cmp cx, 0ah
    jb hexcont4
    add cl, 37h
    jmp hexcont5
hexcont4 :
    add cl, 30h
hexcont5 :
    mov byte ptr [si], cl
    inc si
    mov cx, 0010h
    div cx
    cmp ax, 0000h
    jnz hexconvert

    mov byte ptr [si], '$'
    lea dx,message4
    mov ah,9
    int 21h
    lea dx,hBuffer + 2
    int 21h
    jmp Try

end start
```

Here is my previous output:

[image]

My current code:

```
.model small
.stack
.data
    CR equ 13
    lf equ 10
    Introduction db cr,lf,09H,">This Program converts Decimal into Hexadecimal and Octal Decimal<$"
    Students db cr,lf,09H,"    >TEST<$"
    Lab db cr,lf,09H,09H,09H,">TEST<$"
    Section db cr,lf,09h,09h,09h,09h,">TEST<$"
    Oct db cr,lf,0Ah,09H,">Octal Decimal<$"
    Hexa db cr,lf,0Ah,09H,">Hexadecimal<$"
    message1 db cr,lf,09H,"Enter a decimal number in a range of 0-65535: $"
    message3 db cr,lf,0Ah,09H,09H, "Equivalent octal number is:$"
    message4 db cr,lf,0Ah,09H,09H, "Equivalent hexadecimal number is:$"
    Again db cr,lf,0Ah,09h,"Do you want to try again?(y/n)$"
    Bye db cr,lf,0Ah,09H,09H,09H," >Thank you and Goodbye!<$"

Buffer          dw 6
                dw 0
                    dw 6 dup(0)

Multiplier      dw 0ah

.code
org 100h

start:
    mov cx,0000h
    mov dx,184fh
    mov bh,21h
    mov ah,6
    int 10h

    mov dh,0
    mov dl,0
    mov bh,0
    mov ah,2
    int 10h

    mov ax,@data
    mov ds, ax

    lea dx,Introduction
    mov ah,9
    int 21h

    lea dx,Students
    mov ah,9
    int 21h

    lea dx,Lab
    mov ah,9
    int 21h

    lea dx,Section
    mov ah,9
    int 21h
    jmp Octal   
try:        
lea dx,Again
mov ah,9
int 21h

xor ah,ah
int 16h
mov bl,al

mov dl,al
mov ah,02h
int 21h

cmp bl,'Y'
je start
cmp bl,'y'
je start
cmp bl,'N'
je stop
cmp bl,'n'
je stop
stop :
lea dx,Bye
mov ah,9
int 21h

mov ax,4C00h 
int 21h 
Octal:

lea dx,Oct
mov ah,9
int 21h

mov dx,offset message1
mov ah,09h
int 21h

mov ah, 0ah
lea dx, Buffer
int 21h

mov si, offset Buffer + 2
mov cl, byte ptr [si-1]
mov ch, 00h
OctSubtract :
mov al, byte ptr [si]
cmp al, 30h
jnb OctCont1
jmp stop
OctCont1 :
cmp al, 3ah
jb OctCont2
jmp stop

OctCont2 :
sub al, 30h
mov byte ptr [si], al
inc si
loop OctSubtract
mov si, offset Buffer + 2
mov cl, byte ptr [si-1]
mov ch, 00h
mov ax, 0000h
OctCalc :
mul Multiplier
mov bl, byte ptr [si]
mov bh, 00h
add ax, bx
inc si
loop OctCalc
mov si, offset Buffer + 2
mov bx, ax
mov dx, 0000h
mov ax, 8000h
OctOctConvert :
mov cx, 0000h
OctConv :
cmp bx, ax
jb OctCont3
sub bx, ax
inc cx
jmp OctConv
OctCont3 :
add cl, 30h
mov byte ptr [si], cl
inc si
mov cx, 0008h
div cx
cmp ax, 0000h
jnz OctOctConvert
mov byte ptr [si], '$'

lea dx,message3
mov ah,9
int 21h
mov dx, offset Buffer + 2
int 21h

Hex:
    mov si, offset Buffer + 2
    mov cl, byte ptr [si-1]
    mov ch, 00h
 hexsubtract :
    mov al, byte ptr [si]
    cmp al, 30h
    jnb hexcont1

    jmp stop
 hexcont1 :
    cmp al, 3ah
    jb hexcont2

    jmp stop
 hexcont2 :
    sub al, 30h
    mov byte ptr [si], al

    inc si
    loop hexsubtract

    mov si, offset Buffer + 2
    mov cl, byte ptr [si-1]
    mov ch, 00h
    mov ax, 0000h
 hexcalc :
    mul Multiplier
    mov bl, byte ptr [si]
    mov bh, 00h
    add ax, bx
    inc si
    loop hexcalc

    mov si, offset Buffer + 2
    mov bx, ax
    mov dx, 0000h
    mov ax, 1000h
hexconvert :
    mov cx, 0000h
conv :
    cmp bx, ax
    jb hexcont3
    sub bx, ax
    inc cx
    jmp conv
hexcont3 :
    cmp cx, 0ah
    jb hexcont4
    add cl, 37h
    jmp hexcont5
hexcont4 :
    add cl, 30h
hexcont5 :
    mov byte ptr [si], cl
    inc si
    mov cx, 0010h
    div cx
    cmp ax, 0000h
    jnz hexconvert

    mov byte ptr [si], '$'
    lea dx,message4
    mov ah,9
    int 21h
    lea dx,Buffer + 2
    int 21h
    jmp Try

end start
```

Here is my current output:
[image]

Comment: You already described the answer in your question: store the input value somewhere as a 16-bit integer (after converting from a decimal string).  Take out the code that prompts for input again and replace it with a load of the saved value.

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes. I tried it already but it seems the hexa conversion is not working. I have edited the question to attach the current output.

Comment: just my 2 cents: your code is hard to read, and not well structured. This is why you cannot say if it's the conversion that's not working, or the storing of your entered values. The bigger your programs get, the more important is: Move your converting functions into _reusable_ subroutines (this will also make them easier to test), make sure they're working, and *then* create a "main program" to do the prompts, and call the conversions.

Comment: @Tommylee2k I'm sorry, I just started to learn assembly. I understand the logic behind on how to do it but I don't know how to code it properly in assembly.

Comment: split your task into smaller pieces. one could be "convert ascii string to binary", this could be used to convert your number entered into some register value in AX. one could be "convert AX to octal String", another one "convert AX to hex String". If you have those, all you need to do is prompt your greetings, let the user enter a number, convert it to binary (and save it for later use), then display it in octal, (restore the previous read value), display it in hexa, prompt your "repeat?", stop when 'n'/'N' is pressed etc.
All of this is already there, just in one huge function

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50323055/edit). Thanks in advance.